# How to auto import live currency rates in Magento 2.3.4?

Tags: magento2, checkout, currency, currency-rates, exchange

I'm having a problem with the Magento 2 currency rate. I have a question is it also possible to automate Magento 2.3.4 currencies, for example, JPY, HKD and USD? can you show me the process of how to do it Programmatically or any extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The api for Fixer.io has changed from what Magento has integrated. First of all the url has changed, and secondly the api key must be sent in as a custom header with the key "apikey", not as part of the url. To make these changes in Magento requires a custom module to override the Magento Fixer class.

First of all, the standard files for creating and registering a module:

Dev\FixerIo\registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
   'Dev_FixerIo',
   __DIR__
);
```

Dev\FixerIo\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Dev_FixerIo" setup_version="1.0.1"></module>
</config>
```

Next, we tell Magento to load out FixerIo instead of their own FixerIo:

Dev\FixerIo\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    
    <preference for="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\Import\FixerIo" 
                type="Dev\FixerIo\Model\Currency\Import\FixerIo"
    />
    
</config>
```

And finally, we copy/paste the existing Magento code and make our changes. We have to copy/paste the entire file because Magento have used private scope on a lot of functions / properties instead of protected and we require access to them, so...

The key differences here are line 11 (const CURRENCY_CONVERTER_URL is new api endpoint) and lines 129-132, where we set the headers with our api key.

Dev\FixerIo\Model\Currency\Import\FixerIo.php

```
<?php

namespace Dev\FixerIo\Model\Currency\Import;

use \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class FixerIo extends \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\Import\FixerIo
{
    private $scopeConfig;

    const CURRENCY_CONVERTER_URL = 'https://api.apilayer.com/fixer/latest?symbols{{CURRENCY_TO}}&base={{CURRENCY_FROM}}'; // changed constant
    
    const API_KEY_CONFIG_PATH = 'currency/fixerio/api_key';
    
    /**
     * Initialize dependencies
     *
     * @param \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $httpClientFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $httpClientFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($currencyFactory, $scopeConfig, $httpClientFactory);
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function fetchRates()
    {
        $data = [];
        $currencies = $this->_getCurrencyCodes();
        $defaultCurrencies = $this->_getDefaultCurrencyCodes();

        foreach ($defaultCurrencies as $currencyFrom) {
            if (!isset($data[$currencyFrom])) {
                $data[$currencyFrom] = [];
            }
            $data = $this->convertBatch($data, $currencyFrom, $currencies);
            ksort($data[$currencyFrom]);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Return currencies convert rates in batch mode
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @param string $currencyFrom
     * @param array $currenciesTo
     * @return array
     */
    private function convertBatch(array $data, string $currencyFrom, array $currenciesTo): array
    {
        $accessKey = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::API_KEY_CONFIG_PATH, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        
        if (empty($accessKey)) {
            $this->_messages[] = __('No API Key was specified or an invalid API Key was specified.');
            $data[$currencyFrom] = $this->makeEmptyResponse($currenciesTo);
            return $data;
        }

        $currenciesStr = implode(',', $currenciesTo);
        $url = str_replace(
            ['{{ACCESS_KEY}}', '{{CURRENCY_FROM}}', '{{CURRENCY_TO}}'],
            [$accessKey, $currencyFrom, $currenciesStr],
            self::CURRENCY_CONVERTER_URL
        );
        // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
        set_time_limit(0);
        try {
            $response = $this->getServiceResponse($url);
        } finally {
            ini_restore('max_execution_time');
        }

        if (!$this->validateResponse($response, $currencyFrom)) {
            $data[$currencyFrom] = $this->makeEmptyResponse($currenciesTo);
            return $data;
        }

        foreach ($currenciesTo as $currencyTo) {
            if ($currencyFrom == $currencyTo) {
                $data[$currencyFrom][$currencyTo] = $this->_numberFormat(1);
            } else {
                if (empty($response['rates'][$currencyTo])) {
                    $serviceHost =  $this->getServiceHost($url);
                    $this->_messages[] = __('We can\'t retrieve a rate from %1 for %2.', $serviceHost, $currencyTo);
                    $data[$currencyFrom][$currencyTo] = null;
                } else {
                    $data[$currencyFrom][$currencyTo] = $this->_numberFormat(
                        (double)$response['rates'][$currencyTo]
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $url
     * @param int $retry
     * @return array|mixed
     * @override
     * @see \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency\Import\FixerIo::convertBatch()
     */
    private function getServiceResponse($url, $retry = 0)
    {
        $accessKey = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::API_KEY_CONFIG_PATH, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        
        
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClient $httpClient */
        $httpClient = $this->httpClientFactory->create();
        $response = [];
        
        try {
            
            $jsonResponse = $httpClient->setUri($url)
                ->setConfig(
                    [
                        'timeout' => $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
                            'currency/fixerio/timeout',
                            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                        ),
                    ]
                )
                ->setHeaders([
                    'Content-Type' => 'text/plain',
                    'apikey' => $accessKey,
                ])
                ->request('GET')
                ->getBody();

            $response = json_decode($jsonResponse, true);
            
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            if ($retry == 0) {
                $response = $this->getServiceResponse($url, 1);
            }
        }
        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Validates rates response.
     *
     * @param array $response
     * @param string $baseCurrency
     * @return bool
     */
    private function validateResponse(array $response, string $baseCurrency): bool
    {
        if ($response['success']) {
            return true;
        }

        $errorCodes = [
            101 => __('No API Key was specified or an invalid API Key was specified.'),
            102 => __('The account this API request is coming from is inactive.'),
            105 => __('The "%1" is not allowed as base currency for your subscription plan.', $baseCurrency),
            201 => __('An invalid base currency has been entered.'),
        ];

        $this->_messages[] = $errorCodes[$response['error']['code']] ?? __('Currency rates can\'t be retrieved.');

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Creates array for provided currencies with empty rates.
     *
     * @param array $currenciesTo
     * @return array
     */
    private function makeEmptyResponse(array $currenciesTo): array
    {
        return array_fill_keys($currenciesTo, null);
    }

    /**
     * Get currency converter service host.
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @return string
     */
    private function getServiceHost(string $url): string
    {
        if (!$this->currencyConverterServiceHost) {
            // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
            $this->currencyConverterServiceHost = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME) . '://'
                // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
                . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
        }
        return $this->currencyConverterServiceHost;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to auto update currencies rates in your Magento installation.

Magento has inbuilt functionality to update currency rates.

To configure you need to get API key from either [fixer.io](https://fixer.io/) or [Currency Converter API](https://www.currencyconverterapi.com/)

After getting API key you need to update in configuration at

> Update API key at Stores >> Configuration >> Currency Setup >> (fixer.io/Currency Converter API)

finally enable `Scheduled Import Settings` with service for which you added API key

[image]

**Note:** You only need one API key and can choose any one

Comment: Yes, I did this for Fixer.io, but every time error came up.
"No API Key was specified, or an invalid API Key was specified."
and Currency converter API is only for 2 currencies. I want 3 currencies.

Comment: try to create new API for fixer.io and update configuration.

Comment: Still getting the same error; I tested the key in postman is working, but when I put the key in Magento inbuilt feature and tried to update currency rates using the import button then, an error came up

Comment: Magento version ?

Comment: Magento version 2.3.4

Comment: can you share key over chat room ? it seems there is another issue.

Comment: can debug https://github.com/pawan/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Directory/Model/Currency/Import/FixerIo.php as well.

Comment: KEY =  "va7a2k4CMoVHImX3TQ2fMt9ax6T5c2ur"

Comment: I checked using postman using this URL 
{"CURRENCY_CONVERTER_URL = 'http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key={{ACCESS_KEY}}'. '&base={{CURRENCY_FROM}}&symbols={{CURRENCY_TO}}';"}
Giving 101 error means ("No API Key was specified or an invalid API Key was specified.").

Comment: It seems there is an issue or update in API end point..will create a issue if anyone has idea.

Comment: Is there another way to do it?

Comment: will check a workaround

Comment: Okay, please let me know if found something
Thanks!!

Comment: Hey, I found the bug API URL is changed. {"CURRENCY_CONVERTER_URL = 'api.apilayer.com/fixer/latest?symbols{{CURRENCY_TO}}&base={{CURRENCY_FROM}}';"}

I added an answer to my question.

Comment: Yes, if you create APIkey form API layer it will not work.If you created (older) from fixer.io it will work

Comment: in latest branch they fixed it and added 2 separate fixer services . one for fixer.io and another one is for API layer

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know.